# Banach spaces and Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Please give me a complete proof that a Banach space s may not be a Hilbert space. Solve example which is a Banach space but not Hilbert space

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/302797) to avoid down votes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Banach space that is not a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692522/a-banach-space-that-is-not-a-hilbert-space)

Answer (score 2):

Towards the second part of your question. Consider the set of all continuous functions on a compact interval $[a,b]$ for $a < b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. And the [uniform norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm), $\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty$. Then this set together with this norm, i.e. $(C([a,b]),\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty)$, is a Banach space but not a Hilbert space as the uniform norm is not induced by a scalar product.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is the $l^p$ space for $p \neq 2$. This follows easily from the parallelogram law.