# Orthogonality requirements of basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Do vectors need to be orthogonal to be valid basis vectors? Every point in $R^2$ can be "reached" through linear combinations of the basis vectors $[1,0], [0,1]$, which are indeed orthogonal. But you could substitute the latter vector with $[1,1]$ and still "reach" any point in $R^2$ through linear combinations therein.

So my question, is it required for basis vectors to be orthogonal, just good practice, or am I missing the mark entirely?

Comment: It is required that these vectors span the space. For this to happen they just need to be not colinear. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span Orthogonality may help bring some simplification to calculations but not a requirement

Comment: @CowboyTrader: I am missing something, or you are mixing up the concepts of "begin linear independent" and "spanning the space".

Comment: Basis need to span the whole space in a unique way (linear independence). Being orthogonal (and non zero) is an easy way to warrant the uniqueness. Orthogonality also makes it easy to use the inner product to decompose vectors. But a basis need not be orthogonal.

Comment: [It is possible to span a vector space without there even being a notion of inner product for "orthogonal" to make sense!](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692529)

Comment: Orthogonality is not required, but it makes some things easier.

Comment: As others have mentioned, orthogonality is preferred, but not required. The Gram-Schmidt procedure is capable of taking a linearly independent basis and converting it to an orthonormal basis.